# preg_replace always return original string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace `'<tbody>'` with `'<thead>'` form:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
```

And Here is my code:

```
$reg_exp = "/(^<table.+.(?:[n])?(?:.+)?)(<tbody>)/";
$replace_with = "/1<thead>";
echo $input = '<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>';
$final = preg_replace($reg_exp, $replace_with, $input);

var_dump($final);
```

It prints:

```
string(83) "<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" style="width: 100%;">
<tbody></tbody></table>
```

I can't figure out whats wrong! Please, someone can guide me on how i can do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use a regex for this...BUT your issue is a `.` doesn't match new lines without the `s` modifier.

```
$reg_exp = "/(^<table.+.(?:[n])?(?:.+)?)(<tbody>)/s";
```

https://regex101.com/r/pV7XRd/1/ vs. https://regex101.com/r/pV7XRd/2/

You also should use `$1` or `\\1` for the replacement.

```
$reg_exp = "/(^<table.+.(?:[n])?(?:.+)?)(<tbody>)/s";
$replace_with = '$1<thead>';
$input = '<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>';
$final = preg_replace($reg_exp, $replace_with, $input);
var_dump($final);
```

https://3v4l.org/srNiQ